# The GMP configuration by MSYS2 remains incomplete

Tags: configuration, gmp, msys2

I'm using Windows 7 and the latest version of MSYS2.

For my work I needed to install GMP with MSYS2.

After installing and decompressing, I had to configure the GMP folder with the `./configure` command.

But the problem is that the process starts and always stops at this point.
[image: Configuring problem]
This line is actually one of the configuration preparations where the program stops.

What is the problem and how can it be fixed?

I think I provided enough information. If more information is needed, I can provide it.

Thanks

Comment: Did `./configure` actually fail after saying `no`? Just seeing a `no` in a few lines is not necessarily a problem. Can you provide the full log?

Comment: Why not install a prebuilt GMP from the MSYS2 package manager?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is exactly the problem. The operation doesn't end. Rather, it remains unfinished. Also ,there is no message that shows the work has failed or been successful.
In the case of full log, its too much to display (:

Comment: Upload it to pastebin then.